# orderBy not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something similar to what is done [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), i.e. ordering an array of objects in the view by using the filter `orderBy` (you can find the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExSjseOhSKFCiXNz5x8V?p=preview)). My code is working well but when I add the `orderBy` filter I see nothing in the view. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7GvmzQJCZY7LVunYhfJT?p=preview) is my plunker. In order to see the error, please add `| orderBy:'num'` to line 22 in my `index.html` file. It doesn't work neither with `| orderBy:'id'` or `| orderBy:'label'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line 6 in your script replace :

```
var myArray = [], myObject = {};
```

by :

```
var myArray = [], myObject = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Patrick Ferreira is totally right, just for the explanation if somebody wonders..

The [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter of AngularJS just orders arrays:

> Orders a specified *array* by the *expression* predicate

and array-like values:

> Array-like values (e.g. NodeLists, jQuery objects, TypedArrays, Strings, etc) are also supported.